# echo a variable differs between the unix distributions

Tags: shell-script, echo

i have a simple shell script that echoes variable in a file but i have issues getting it work the same way between the different distributions.

The script

```
#!/bin/sh
res="=1B,\=AB=D2=DB=B5=A6e=FCj=10=0C=EE=91@y\e=082  ="
echo $res
```

The the result in Ubuntu 20.04.3

```
=1B,\=AB=D2=DB=B5=A6e=FCj=10=0C=EE=91@y082 =
```

And result in CentOS 6.0

```
=1B,\=AB=D2=DB=B5=A6e=FCj=10=0C=EE=91@y\e=082 =
```

Why Ubuntu is not printing the "\e" and how to make it print it?

Comment: See [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo), in particular the discussion around the `-e` flag

Comment: Already tested printf but it brings other issues that i was unable to solve so i prefer echo. This script is used by Amavis to add disclaimer to email file before sending it out. If i use printf "%s" "$res" > /path/to/file then the DKIM signature added by Amavis is invalid. If using echo the DKIM signature is fine.

Comment: Perhaps the signature needs to end in a newline? `printf "%s\n" "$res" > /path/to/file`

Comment: Yes, newline fixed it. Thank you very much!

Comment: `/bin/sh` in Ubuntu is Dash by default, CentOS probably has Bash. And their implementations of `echo` differ in how they treat backslash escapes. Bash only processes them with `-e`, and Dash doesn't seem to have a way to disable it.